# Getting value after second - in php

Tags: php

I have E-20-99 in a string i want to get last value 99 and add 1 means 100 and then wants to generate new string E-20-100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string ALWAYS looks like this, you can easily break it without a regex, simply by using `explode()`

```
$string = "E-20-99";
$parts = explode('-', $string);

$last_part = $parts[2] + 1;
$parts[2] = $last_part;

$string = implode('-', $parts);

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always E-20-XX you can use

```
$n = ((int)substr('E-20-99', strlen('E-20-')))+1;
echo 'E-20-' . $n;
```

If the string might vary a bit more you could use a regualar expressions such as:

```
$string = 'E-20-99';
preg_match('/(E-\d+-)(\d+)/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1] . ((int)$match[2] + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$old_str = 'E-20-99';
$new_str = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=-)\d+$/', function($matches) {
  return $matches[0] + 1;
}, $old_str);
```